# Insert product id into custom table while importing products in Magento from csv

Tags: magento-1.9, import, module

I have created a custom admin module using module creator with **entity type "Flat"** and it created  2 table in my database.

Now I need to insert product id in one of table when importing products from csv. Can anybody please help me to achieve this.

Comment: can anyone help me please?

Comment: yes,  i will help you

Comment: Please let me know how I can do above mentioned task.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `magento event/observer`.

On  `catalog_product_save_after` fire run  `observer` which will work for `admin section`.

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
      <catalog_product_save_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <catalog_product_save_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento62659/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>fetchproductData</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </catalog_product_save_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

and Observer code is  like:

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento62659_Model_Observer
{

    public function fetchproductData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
        if($action->getFullActionName()!='adminhtml_catalog_product_save'):
        $actin=$action->getFullActionName('-');
        Mage::log('+++'.$actin,null,'my.log');
        // do your code
        endif;

    }

}
```

Comment: What is this `$p` you're logging? You also don't need the `endif` bit as you're in a class, it's all PHP, use brackets.

Comment: @Amit Bera, can you please help me with the same requirment for magento 2?

Comment: sure.i will help ...